# How to select a file from popup selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

Im trying to upload a video using selenium python, whenever i try to upload it i get a pop up window to choose the file. how can i automate this task to select file from the popup window?

Comment: can you share the HTML and code you tried?

Answer (score 0):

If the page HTML have this CSS_SELECTOR :

```
input[type='file']
```

you can just do `send_keys`.

something like this  :

```
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get("Your URL")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "LocationSearch_input"))).send_keys("full path of file to be uploaded")
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```